# Eclipse Plugin Instatllation Error - Jetty

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty

Trying to install Jetty plugin for Eclipse from this link: http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/updates/jetty-bundles-9.x/9.3.6.v20151106

I've been stumped for the past two days from the following error (the plugin cannot install without the dependency). How do I let the plugin access these dependencies? The documentation is not very straightforward with that.

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Jetty - Bundles: all the jetty bundles 9.3.6.201511131804 (org.eclipse.jetty.bundles.f.feature.group 9.3.6.201511131804)
  Missing requirement: Jetty-OSGi-Jasper Integration 9.3.6.v20151106 (org.eclipse.jetty.osgi.boot.jsp 9.3.6.v20151106) requires 'package javax.servlet.jsp [2.3.0,2.4.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Jetty - Bundles: all the jetty bundles 9.3.6.201511131804 (org.eclipse.jetty.bundles.f.feature.group 9.3.6.201511131804)
    To: org.eclipse.jetty.osgi.boot.jsp [9.3.6.v20151106]

Comment: which java version are you using?

Comment: Java 8. Have tried adding javax.servlet.jsp to classpath, downloaded Jave EE.

Comment: something similar is being discussed here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=481785

Comment: @Vijay They are discussing an even older version, which matches what I think it's happening. Their version is 9.3.5.201510142109.

Comment: I've already visited that back Vijay. "I think you'll need to firstly install the suggested 3rd party dependencies" - I understand I have to do that. But where do I install these dependencies so the the plugin download succeeds?

Answer (score 0):

By the data you provided I can infer that your problem lies in the fact that with JAVA 8 you need a new version of jetty.

You should try [the Jetty plugin](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/) page. You will see that

1. The version you are trying to install is: 9.3.6.201511131804
2. The version Jetty says to be only compatible with Java 8 is 9.3.7.v20160115

You are a version number down the line. Well technically they should be both compatible since in theory it's intended to be compatible upwards.

On side note I just installed your exact version in my eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) with Java 8 and had no problems with it.

Comment: ... how are you installing it? I'm trying to install this as a plugin so that I can add it as a plugin dependency for an Eclipse plugin that I am developing.

Comment: I'm basically using the standard eclipse installation using the URL provided in the website. it could be that your Java EE installation just got corrupt. I would try a couple of things: 1. Remove all Java EE related installation from eclipse, restart eclipse, reinstall and restart again. 2. Just reinstall eclipse and then install Java EE. (you can find that in the section  **Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development** for your eclipse plugin installation url).

Comment: what URL are you using?

Comment: I mean the one you mention http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/updates/jetty-bundles-9.x/9.3.6.v20151106 . That one actually works for me as well. That's why I think your eclipse Java EE installation may be corrupt.